# How do I make a sphere with 5 flat sides?

Tags: modeling

What it says in the title, I'm trying to make a sphere with 5 flat sides so I can place a cone on top each one in a star esque pattern but I have no idea how to do so. Ideally they'd want to be equal in radius. Thanks for reading.

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platonic_solid Only these can have truly equal sides.

Comment: It sounds like you don't have a clear picture of what you want, or you haven't described it well, because 1) a sphere doesn't have sides, 2) a 5-sided solid can't have equal faces 3) a 5-sided volume would have 5 vertices, which seems REALLY straightforward to model. **So** I recommend updating your question with something specific that you've tried, but hasn't worked, or a particular part of the process that you're finding difficult (e.g. "I have a 5-sided solid, but how can I make all the faces equal?", or "How do I make sure that each of my vertices is the same distance from the center?")

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](http://pasteall.org/pic/68154)?

Comment: gandalf3 has the right idea. What I mean is a sphere with 5 flattened planes going radially in a circle, similar to that image.

Comment: Ideally my result would be similar to [this](http://puu.sh/7sSCs.png) except all as one mesh, instead of a few cones stuck onto a sphere.

Comment: To simplify the question to the problem I'm having. How do I make a Circular hole on the surface of a sphere?

Comment: hmmm, now you're asking a slightly different question. Do you need to update/clarify your original question?

Comment: This doesn't need to be closed at this point, but Broand really needs to figure out what exactly he's trying to ask. Broand, please sketch it on paper and upload a scan or something. Just get your question straight so we can answer it in a constructive way.

Answer (score 4):

Another method:

1. Add a sphere (both types will work).
2. Add a cylinder with five verts:

   [image]
3. Add a boolean modifier to the sphere and select the cylinder as the object:

   [image]

   Scaling the cylinder on the X and Y (<kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>) axes will change the radii of the flatten areas.
4. Apply the modifier and select the flat faces (the fastest was is probably by selecting one and pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>*> Area*):

   [image]
5. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> and the select the center vertices:

   [image]
6. Scale the vertices out (<kbd>S</kbd>). Then optionally set shading to smooth and add an edge split modifier:

   [image]

Answer (score 3):

The simplest method would be to use a bolean modifier:

1. Add Sphere
2. Add Cone
3. Go to Modifiers
4. Select Generate->Boolean
5. Operation -> Union
6. Object -> Cone
7. Apply

[image: Boolean Modifier]

To distribute 5 cones around a point:

1. Create Cone
2. Move cone above rotation point (0,0,0)
3. Go into edit mode
4. Add -> Spin

   5. Set Center of rotation (0,0,0)
   6. Angle -> 360
   7. Axis -> X -> non-zero

[image]